# Azure DevOp- Deployment Group- Bring target VM online

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops

In my release pipeline I had configured a deployment group with one VM.
The VM got shutdown over weekend, and after that even if VM is online the status in deployment group
is still Offline, not sure how update status in deployment group.
I tried to register again, but getting error has attached in image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEjLB.png)

The service already exists: vstsagent.eclinicaltfs.OnPoint-CTMS1.0.0 DG.AZDEVOPVALSP02, it will be replaced
Could not delete service 'vstsagent.eclinicaltfs.OnPoint-CTMS1.0.0 DG.AZDEVOPVALSP02'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First check if the agent is running on your server, searching on Windows Services for Azure Pipeline Agent. It will have the name appended to the name of the service. Start it if it is not running and go back to deployment groups to see if it is online. It not, it could be your firewall.

[image]

Then stop the Windows Service, open a command prompt and go to path where your agent is installed on the prompt. Then execute the run.cmd. This will run the agent in the console you will see if it can connect your azure devops account. If the error message says the agent cannot find or reach the azure devops server, then your firewall is blocking it.

Third, you can try to select `Update targets` to upgrade the agent on the target machine to the latest version to see if it works.

[image]

If nothing else works, try to reinstall the agent.

Comment: Good Explanation, just want to know after running the script why the agent is online.